# how to get list of all points in a multipolygon in Python?

Tags: python, networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I have a `csv` file that contains a column that contains `multipolygon` representation of NYC. Meaning, NYC is divided into multi-polygons and those multi-polygons are stored in a column called `the_geom` in the `csv` file I have.

My question is how can I get the list of all possible points in each `multipolygon`?
What I have done so far is simply pick a random point in a `multipolygon`, then check if the selected point is contained in the `multipolygon`, the code to do so is:

```
multipolygon = shapely.wkt.loads(row['the_geom'])
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = multipolygon.bounds

pnt1 = Point(random.uniform(minx, maxx), random.uniform(miny, maxy))
while not multipolygon.contains(pnt1):
    pnt1 = Point(random.uniform(minx, maxx), random.uniform(miny, maxy))
```

How do I get the list of all points within a `multipolygon`?
Should I convert each `multipolygon` to a `polygon` first so I can get the list of all possible points in each `multipolygon`?

I have seen solutions is google that suggests using `GeoPandas.explode()`, but I'm not sure if it is the correct approach to convert `multipolygon` to `polygon` or not.

I'd like to know what is the correct way to get a list of all points within a `multipolygon`, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the list of all points defining the boundary lines (edges) of the multipolygon? There are of course infinite points inside a polygon so we can’t list  them all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In that case, is there a way to convert a Multipolygon to a Polygon?

Comment: no. but you could loop through all of the polygon boundary coordinates in a multipolygon by accessing the `.geoms` attribute, e.g. with `np.hstack([np.array(g.boundary.xy) for g in multipolygon.geoms])`

Comment: just to make sure I understand, the code snippet iterates through the boundaries of each polygon of each Multipolygon, which means the points in each iteration will be in the border of a polygon, not inside the polygon. Am I correct?

Comment: yes. it's completely impossible to enumerate the points inside a polygon. so I took your question to mean you want the points which define the boundary. if you want points within the polygon, you'll have to specify how you want to sample the space.

Comment: got it, I will use the code snippet you suggested. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tested your suggestion and I think it is the best that can be done! Thank you so much! any way I can vote your comment as a solution?

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

To get all points defining the boundaries of the polygons which make up the MultiPolygon, you can iterate through the shapes using the [`MultiPolygon.bounds`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#MultiPolygon) attribute, e.g.:

```py
np.hstack([np.array(g.boundary.xy) for g in multipolygon.geoms])
```